# ReactJS ternary operator with boolean props

Tags: reactjs, ternary

I am trying to use ternary operator with a boolean props

The app.js is as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import  HouseFull  from './HouseFull';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1> Hello2 </h1>
    <HouseFull hasOpening="{false}" />


    </div>
    
  );
}
```

The react component is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HouseFull extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 
                <h1> {this.props.hasOpening} </h1>
                <h1> {this.props.hasOpening ? "Available" : "No Vacancy"} </h1>
                
            </div>
        )

    }

}

export default HouseFull;
```

The result of the second h1 tag is the same, if I pass hasOpening as true or false
If I pass true, following is displayed

```
{true}
available
```

If I pass false, following is displayed

```
{false}
available
```

I am suspecting something is wrong in the statement with the ternary operator, but cannot figure out. The value of the boolean flag is reflected properly in the first h1 tag in the outpur

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string as props in . You need to pass boolean.

```
<HouseFull hasOpening={false} />
```

Otherwise, you will have to check in the HouseFull component in the following manner,

```
 <h1> {this.props.hasOpening === "{false}" ? "Available" : "No Vacancy"} </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, How do I mark this question as resolved ?

Comment: You can click the tick sign under vote count in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is okey, but you are passing down a *string* instead of a *boolean*. Non-empty string will always evaluate to *true*, that's why nothing happens when you toggle it.

```
hasOpening={false}
```